# LitElement : Not working in a modified Firefox version

Tags: javascript, lit-element

I'm trying to integrate LitElement in a project for work. It works on all browsers, except on a modified Firefox which has `customElements` disabled. Is there any way to get around this? If I turn in on in `about:config` Asking users to activate it is not an option.

The component code:

```
import {html, LitElement, property} from 'lit-element';

class MyElement extends LitElement {
  @property({type: String}) myProp = 'stuff';
  render() {
    return html`
      <p>Hello World</p>
      ${this.myProp}
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

Comment: Have you looked at: https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements

Answer (score 2):

> LitElement uses Custom Elements for easy inclusion in web pages, and Shadow DOM for encapsulation. There’s no new abstraction on top of the web platform.

If Custom Elements are disabled, I wouldn't expect LitElement to work.

However, you could try a polyfill for `customElements` like https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements – while it's meant for browsers that don't support `customElements`, I imagine it could also work in a situation where the feature is disabled.